# Why (from Stream) is filter + findFirst + isPresent faster than filter + anyMatch?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This question is probably going to be silly, but I have been thinking about it for a few days now and haven't been able to find an answer.

I was writing a function recently and IntelliJ gave me a highlight hint suggesting I change a line which finds if an element exists in a collection with a particular parameter present. I streamed a Set as the collection, and my line was something like:

```
boolean result1 = numbers.stream().filter(n -> {
            return n.number == 5;
        }).findFirst().isPresent();
```

The suggested change from IntelliJ was to use the `anyMatch` method as follows:

```
boolean result2 = numbers.stream().anyMatch(n -> {
            return n.number == 5;
        });
```

The suggestion from IntelliJ is technically correct - `anyMatch` returns the exact value I am expecting, but for some reason I wanted to test it against the original method used which returns Optional and see just how much faster it was - but for some reason it wasn't. The tests kept showing that the original was almost always twice (or more) times faster than `anyMatch`.

Is this a hardware/software/environment issue? Am I looking at this too simplistically? I can't put my finger on what is possibly going on here.

The performance test I was running was as follows:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class TestObject {
        int number;

        TestObject(int num) {
            this.number = num;
        }
    }

    Set<TestObject> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    Set<TestObject> numbers1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<TestObject> numbers2 = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        numbers.add(new TestObject(i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        numbers1.add(new TestObject(i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        numbers2.add(new TestObject(i));
    }

    Long start = System.nanoTime();

    boolean result = numbers.stream().anyMatch(n -> {
        return n.number == 500;
    });
    System.out.println("Time to find - anyMatch: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));

    start = System.nanoTime();
    result = numbers.stream().filter(n -> {;
        return n.number == 500;
    }).findFirst().isPresent();
    System.out.println("Time to find - filter + findFirst + isPresent: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));

    result = numbers.stream().anyMatch(n -> {
        return n.number == 5000;
    });
    System.out.println("Time to find - anyMatch: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));

    start = System.nanoTime();
    result = numbers.stream().filter(n -> {
        return n.number == 5000;
    }).findFirst().isPresent();
    System.out.println("Time to find - filter + findFirst + isPresent: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));

    result = numbers.stream().anyMatch(n -> {
        return n.number == 50000;
    });
    System.out.println("Time to find - anyMatch: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));

    start = System.nanoTime();
    result = numbers.stream().filter(n -> {
        return n.number == 50000;
    }).findFirst().isPresent();
    System.out.println("Time to find - filter + findFirst + isPresent: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your performance test in the question.

Comment: Apologies. Threw it in just now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the results with JMH. They take approximately the same amount of time. Can you do the same tests with [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh)?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/5133585

Comment: This is almost certainly a flaw in your measurement technique, not a reflection of the real behavior.

Comment: I accept that argument @LouisWasserman and knew it was probably the case. A lot of my confusion stemmed from being able to switch around the methods, and the anyMatch method would still appear slower. I just ran through JMH as suggested by Sweeper and can see they are in fact extremely similar, which still confuses me to be honest.

Comment: Why would that be surprising?  They're computing the same result, you'd hope they optimize to the same thing.

Comment: In tests in the post you are missing `start = System.nanoTime();` before you start the `anyMatch` tests (except before the very first test)

Comment: Unless you really need the first occurrence, I would use `findAny` over `findFirst`. For sequential streams they probably do the same, but for parallel streams an order is imposed, which may lead to unnecessary blocking.